# NSPredicate question

Tags: ios, mkmapview, nspredicate

I want to delete all annotations except RestaurantLocation or GrayRestaurantLocation.

is it correct version ?

```
[mapView removeAnnotations:[mapView.annotations 
    filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
       @"! ( (self isKindOfClass: %@) AND (self isKindOfClass: %@) )", 
      [RestaurantLocation class], [GrayRestaurantLocation class]]] ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An annotation can't be both a RestaurantLocation AND a GrayRestaurantLocation.

Change the `AND` to `OR`.